# Error: Argument of type 'Node' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseType'

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I inherited a codebase which uses d3.js stack component. When I try to compile the Angular code I receive the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/components/universal/column-chart/column-chart.component.ts(238,28): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Node' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseType'.
>      Type 'Node' is not assignable to type 'EnterElement'.
>      Property 'querySelector' is missing in type 'Node'.

The code which causes this error is the line `return d3.select(...`

```
stacks.append('text')
  .text(d => {
    return `$${ d['total'].spent.amount }`;
  })
  .attr('y', (d, i, j) => {
    return d3.select(j[i]['parentNode']).select('.bar')['_groups'][0][0]['y'].baseVal.value - 5;
  });
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, please try `return d3.select(j[i].parentNode).select('.bar').node().y.baseVal.value - 5;`.

Comment: As the question is now the problem is, probably, unnecessarily hard to attack. Please try to narrow down the exact position of the error in the chained expression by breaking it down into smaller expressions preserving and evaluating their values for debugging purposes. Also, it would be of a great help if you could set up a [mcve] to play around with.

Comment: In addition to the above comment by @GerardoFurtado you could make it even simpler: `.attr("y", function() { return d3.select(this.parentElement).select(".bar").attr("y") - 5; })`.